# Multicollinearity and differences between independent variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

I am trying to estimate a model of attrition that takes into account characteristics of an individual's current job and characteristics of an individual's residency. Of particular interest is how the difference between experiences can negatively or positively influence retention rates. However, including a particular characteristic from an individuals current job, their residency, and the difference between these two results in collinearity.

For example, if I am interested in the effect that the percent of individuals working more than 40 hours a week has on attrition, a model including the % working more than 40 hours a week at the current job placement, the % working more than 40 hours a week at an individual's residency location, and the difference between these two would be perfectly collinear.

What is a better way to include a variable for this difference, while still controlling for the percent working more than 40 hours a week?

Comment: This is unrelated to your main question, but when you say "attrition", are you building survival models? What do you mean by "attrition" here?

Comment: Yes, I am building model to predict leaving the workforce.